# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, but only one is allowed - cannot forward request

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following setup:

- React application hosted on test domain - amplifyapp.com
- Keycloak authorization server
- Spring Gateway behind ngix reverse proxy.

Nginx is used as a reverse proxy to offload SSL encryption.

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name api1.domain.org;
    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/bmiapp.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/bmiapp-error.log error;

    set $cors_credentials '';
set $cors_content_type '';
set $cors_content_length '';

if ($http_origin ~ '.+') {
    set $cors_credentials 'true';
}

if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    set $cors_content_type 'text/plain';
    set $cors_content_length '0';
}

# empty header will not be added
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials $cors_credentials always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods $http_access_control_request_method always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers $http_access_control_request_headers always;
add_header Content-Type $cors_content_type;
add_header Content-Length $cors_content_length;

if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    return 204;
}

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://ip:8134;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api1.domain.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api1.domain.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    server_name api2.domain.org;
    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/bmiapp.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/bmiapp-error.log error;

    set $cors_credentials '';
set $cors_content_type '';
set $cors_content_length '';

if ($http_origin ~ '.+') {
    set $cors_credentials 'true';
}

if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    set $cors_content_type 'text/plain';
    set $cors_content_length '0';
}

# empty header will not be added
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials $cors_credentials always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods $http_access_control_request_method always;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers $http_access_control_request_headers always;
add_header Content-Type $cors_content_type;
add_header Content-Length $cors_content_length;

if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    return 204;
}


    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://ip:8138;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api2.domain.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api2.domain.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = api1.domain.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name api1.domain.org;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = api2.domain.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name api2.domain.org;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

When I try to fetch some data from BE I get error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api2.domain.org/api/microservice/dashboard/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, http://localhost:3000', but only one is allowed.
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Make sure Spring is not returning any `Access-Control-xxxx` HTTP headers - and set them on nginX only.

Comment: Can I disable this using a configuration?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Spring.